# Accessing props in async function, odd results

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-props

These console log statements are printed when I move from "/search/?q=A" to "/search/?q=B" ("executeSearch") is triggered when this happens)

The first two show what I expect to see, as I look through the console log statements to props > history > location > state > queryString, I see "B".

However, in the last three statements, I see "A". Which makes no sense. All the console.log statements should be looking at the same props, should they not? This is consistently what happens as I move through multiple "executeSearch" events. How can I the correct queryString ("B")?

```
  async function getAllData() {
    const query = props.history.location.state.queryString;
    console.log("props: ", props );    //can find "B"
    console.log("props.history: ", props.history );  //can find "B"
    console.log("props.history.location: ", props.history.location );  //cannot find "B", only "A"
    console.log("props.history.location.state: ", props.history.location.state );  //only "A"
    console.log("props.history.location.state.queryString: ", props.history.location.state.queryString );  //only "A"
    console.log("query in getAllData: ", query); //"query" ends up being "A", the query for the previous page
    if (query === "") {
      return [];
    }
    return fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/search/?name=${query}`).then((res) =>
  res.json()
    );
  }

async function getMyResults() {
    let namedData = await getAllData();
    try {
      return namedData["search_results"];
    } catch (err) {
      return "empty";
    }
  }

  const { isFetching, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(
    "getMyResults",
    () => getMyResults(),
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
    }
  );

  window.addEventListener("executeSearch", () => refetch());
```